# Rxjs http chained request error handling

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

In the following code, consider each switchMap as step.

Step 1 : Create user if not already available

Step 2 : Create conversation

Step 3 : Return Response or Error

We might get business side exception in step 1 or step 2 and would like to handle  it elegantly. Do we have better way of handling this ? e.g. Just skip step 2 if we get error in step 1. We tried a lot but not able to get better solution. If we simply throw error in step 1

> Observable.throw(error)

automatic unsubscribtion is happening.

```
const createNewConversationEpic: Epic<Action<{}>, RootState> = (
  action$: ActionsObservable<Action<Conversation | User | Error>>
) => {
  return action$
    .ofType(ConversationsActions.CREATE_NEW_CONVERSATION).pipe(
      switchMap((action: Action<User>) => {
        return action.payload.id
          ? Observable.of(action.payload)
          : createNewLead(action.payload).pipe(
            map(data => data),
            catchError(error => {
              return Observable.of(error);
            })
          );
      }),
      switchMap((response) => {
        if (!(response instanceof Error)) {
          return createNewConversation({ userId: response.id.toString() }).pipe(
            map(data => ConversationsActions.CreateNewConversationSuccess(data)),
            catchError(error => {
              return Observable.of(error);

            })
          );
        } else {
          return Observable.of(response);

        }

      }),
      switchMap(response => {

        if (response instanceof Error) {
          return ActionsObservable.of(
            ConversationsActions.CreateNewConversationError(response),
            ConversationsActions.MessagingGlobalError(response),
            ConversationsActions.ResetMessagingGlobalError()
          );
        } else {
          return Observable.of(response);
        }
      })
    );
};

export const createNewLead = (body: {}) => {
  return request('/api/v1/lead/create/mobile', AjaxMethod.POST, body);
};

const request = (path: string, method: AjaxMethod, body: {}) => {
  const url = path;

  return ajax({
    body,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getAuthToken(),
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method,
    responseType: 'json',
    timeout: 120000, // 2 min
    url
  })
    .map(e => {
      console.log('[AJAX] Status --- ' + e.status);
      console.log(e.response);
      return e.response;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);

      let error = 'Error while executing request';

      if (err.status === 400 || err.status === 412) {
        if (err.response.error) {
          error = err.response.error;
        } else {
          error = err.response.message;
        }
      }

      // Handle 401 Status
      if (err.status === 401) {
        clearLocalstorage();

        window.location.href =
          window.location.origin +
          '/authentication/?src=' +
          window.location.pathname;
      }

      if (err.status === 403) {
        error = 'Oops! Looks like you don\'t have access to it';
      }

      return Observable.throw(new Error(error));
    });
};
```

Comment: _"like to handle it elegantly"_ What does that mean? _"automatic unsubscribtion is happening"_  Don't you want that?

Comment: "like to handle it elegantly"  Just skip step 2 if we get error in step 1. "automatic unsubscription is happening" Don't you want that ? I am loosing action binding and  actions are not triggered once we throw exception.

Comment: _"Just skip step 2 if we get error in step 1"_ That's the default behavior. I don't know what _"action binding"_ means in this context (I assume you use some library), but the subscriber should handle errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to halt the automatic unsubscribe, you just need to wrap the pipeline that you expect to have an error in another stream that can handle the exception, just like you would a standard try/catch, as long as you capture the error and handle it before returning to the outer stream the parent subscription remains intact.

```
const createNewConversationEpic: Epic<Action<{}>, RootState> = (
  action$: ActionsObservable<Action<Conversation | User | Error>>
) => {
  return action$
    .ofType(ConversationsActions.CREATE_NEW_CONVERSATION).pipe(
      // Parent Stream
      switchMap((action: Action<User>) => 
        // Start child stream
        iif(() => action.payload.id, 
          Observable.of(action.payload), 
          createNewLead(action.payload)
        ).pipe(

         // Process event as a "happy-path" since errors get forwarded to the end
         switchMap((response) => createNewConversation({ userId: response.id.toString() })),
         // Move this inline with the rest of the inner pipe line.
         map(data => ConversationsActions.CreateNewConversationSuccess(data)),

         // Catch all errors from this inner pipeline this will stop them from
         // propagating to the outer stream.
         catchError(e => ActionsObservable.of(
            ConversationsActions.CreateNewConversationError(e),
            ConversationsActions.MessagingGlobalError(e),
            ConversationsActions.ResetMessagingGlobalError()
         )
       )
     )
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this. What is "iif" operator when we are starting child stream?

Comment: `iif` is defined [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/iif). It picks an Observable to subscribe to based on the provided predicate. You can think of it like a functional version of `if/else`

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working for me. If we get any error in the child stream (createNewLead), still it's going to createNewConversation , doesn't go directly to catchError. We are using RxJS 5.5.8 with redux-observable 0.18.0.

Comment: Can you share your code for `createNewLead` then? An error from anywhere in the stream will always propagate to the nearest downstream error handler.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into this?

Comment: Its hard to tell, the implementation of your request seems correct, if a message is making it to the `createNewConversation` from `createNewLead` (using the implementation I showed) then you have to be catching it somewhere.